# why timestamp value is null on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use Goldilocks Database seems like Oracle.

I have one record on the Database.

```
gSQL> desc POSTS

COLUMN_NAME    TYPE                           IS_NULLABLE
-------------- ------------------------------ -----------
NU             NUMBER                         TRUE
NAME           CHARACTER VARYING(4000)        TRUE
DATE_TEST      DATE                           TRUE
TIMESTAMP_TEST TIMESTAMP(6) WITHOUT TIME ZONE TRUE
CREATED_AT     TIMESTAMP(6) WITHOUT TIME ZONE TRUE
UPDATED_AT     TIMESTAMP(6) WITHOUT TIME ZONE TRUE


gSQL> SELECT NU, NAME, DATE_TEST, TIMESTAMP_TEST FROM POSTS;

NU NAME DATE_TEST           TIMESTAMP_TEST
-- ---- ------------------- --------------------------
 4 qwe  2018-03-14 00:00:00 2018-03-23 00:59:00.000000

1 row selected.
```

When I put the record on the server console of ruby on rails, I get NULL Only for time-related variables.

Here is source and console.

```
@posts.each do |post|

    if (post.nu == nil) then
      puts '[null] "' + post.nu + '"'
    else
      puts post.nu.to_s
    end

    if (post.name == nil) then
      puts '[null] "' + post.name + '"'
    else
      puts post.name.to_s
    end

    if (post.date_test == nil) then
      puts '[null] "' + post.date_test.to_s + '"'
    else
      puts post.date_test.to_s
    end

    if (post.timestamp_test == nil) then
      puts '[null] "' + post.timestamp_test.to_s + '"'
    else
      puts post.timestatmp_test.to_s
    end

    puts '[API TIME] ' + Time.now.to_s
end
```

server output

```
Started GET "/posts" for 192.168.0.40 at 2018-03-08 14:53:28 +0900
Processing by PostsController#index as HTML
  Post Load (6.8ms)  SELECT posts.* FROM posts
4
qwe
[null] ""
[null] ""
[API TIME] 2018-03-08 15:02:07 +0900
  Rendering posts/index.html.erb within layouts/application
```

What should I do?

Comment: Try this if that can do a trick : `post.date_test.to_s(:db)`

Comment: Unfortunatelly, post.date_test value is null. So I can't do that.  ref. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240239/how-to-debug-an-wrong-number-of-arguments-1-for-0-in-rails-error